# Is there an alternative to the word "coincidence" to describe when two say the same word spontaneously?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a scenario where two people having a conversation utter the same word/phrase together, simultaneously, and unconsciously? Something else than just a coincidence.

Comment: The answer depends on what you're trying to express. "just a coincidence" is a phrase, not a word, and "something else than" suggests a belief that there's some non-coincidental cause, such as telepathy.

Comment: In German we have a saying that translates to "Two idiots, one thought" :-). Usually only used when you are one of the two yourself.

Comment: Because of the close relevance of 'hivemind' and 'synchronicity', it would be best if you clarified the description of the situation.  The experiential value of the synchronous speech can changed the appropriate word.

Comment: @user3448 dict.cc translates this saying to ["Great minds think alike."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+minds+think+alike). My feeling is that the English expression is quite dull in comparison to the German expression.

Answer (score 15):

A *[jinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_%28children%27s_game%29)*.

> A common slang term used when two people say the same thing at the same time, said as a game among children.

Comment: maybe not unconsciously.

Comment: Many people do this (and I've done it), without the sense of it being a "jinx" in the more usual sense.  This "jinx" being different from the superstitious "jinx".

Comment: (and +1 when I get my vote quota refreshed.... )

Comment: I understand the meaning of jinx in the usual and the unusual sense. Just that this answer does not fit into my expectations.

Comment: @n0nChun: It is usually unintentional. I changed the link in my answer to give more information.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Though the game may be based on the phenomenon, the name of the game may not necessarily be able to describe the phenomenon, right?

Comment: @n0nChun: You're right, it may be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I've never heard this use. Is it American, or am I just unaware of what kids say to each other?

Comment: @Colin  Not always kids, but any age, done playfully. Probably regional or otherwise culturally variable.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Well, it's certainly current usage in the chat...

Comment: @Martha: do you know any other word for this?

Comment: Here (in Oklahoma) kids usually follow it with "...owe me a soda!". The odd thing about this is that we are in an area where carbonated soft drinks are "pop", not "soda". So the phrase is clearly an import.

Answer (score 3):

A phrase often used for saying or thinking the same thing as someone else is "[great minds think alike](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/great_minds_think_alike)", which is like the German phrase @user3448 pointed out in a comment.

*Great minds think alike* has a [history back to at least the 17th century](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/great-minds-think-alike.html):

> Dabridgcourt Belchier wrote this in Hans Beer-Pot, 1618:
>   *Though he made that verse, Those words were made before. Good wits doe jumpe.*
>   That citation uses 'jump' with a meaning long since abandoned in everyday speech, that is 'agree with; completely coincide'.

In my experience as an American English speaker, it's often acceptable in places, such as with professional colleagues, where calling "Jinx!" might come across as childish or inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A certain stripe of person will refer to this as a *hivemind* moment.  Others would call it a *synchronicity*, though I'm a little dubious that the event calls for that word's vaguely mystical implications, and might prefer *synchronism*.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a scientific term.

Comment: @n0nChun: I would've have called any of those scientific.

Comment: "would've have called" -- I presume you mean "would not have called". Certainly those are not scientific terms.

Comment: @Jim Balter: Yes, I meant wouldn't have called.

Comment: +1 for synchronicity.  Blech, but it's what I thought of as well.

Comment: agreed that Synchronicity **would not** be appropriate in this context.  More meaning or value must be assigned to the synchronous events.

Answer (score 2):

You could say the two people said [the same word] *in stereo*. Or one of the speakers could just say *Stereo!* as noted [here](http://stereo.urbanup.com/1664478) from Urban Dictionary:

> When two people say the same word or phrase simultaneously during a conversation (usually by coincidence), the word "stereo" would then be uttered immediately by one or both parties to acknowledge this phenomenon.

Of course, if both parties say *stereo* in stereo, then one would have to say [Jinx!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17120/coincidence-is-not-the-only-word/17122#17122)

Answer (score 2):

What one says is "snap" — based on the card game of the same name. (British/Australian English — cf. "jinx" in US English.)

Answer (score 1):

Jinx.  (It's a race to see which of the two people says "jinx" first after they've unintentionally but simultaneously said exactly the same thing.  The victor may add something like "you owe me a Coke.")

Answer (score 0):

People simultaneously utter exactly the same word, phrase or exclamation especially when they are thinking [of] the same thing in exactly the same way. The best word I can think of at the moment to describe this situation is [*telepathy/telepathic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telepathy). I use this word all the time to describe situations such as this, using sentences like:

> - Wow, that was telepathic!!
> - Ooh, some telepathy at work!
> - We got some telepathy going.

Another adjective that could be used to describe this context is [*psychic*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1281525#m_en_us1281525):

> - Wow, you guys said exactly the same thing at the same time! That was *soooo* psychic!

Comment: Telepathy is a broad term, I wonder if there is a term whose scope is narrower than telepathy. Still, it's better than calling it J!nx

Comment: 'Telepathy' might pseudoscientifically describe *how* it happened but it's not a word for the event itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "concurrence".  Or more awkwardly, a "convergence of events".

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they spoke in [unison](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unison):

> simultaneous performance or utterance of **action** or **speech**:
>   *‘Yes, sir,’ said the girls in **unison***

[Chorus](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chorus) might be a stretch. But it *is* related:

> a **simultaneous utterance** of something by many people:
>   *a growing chorus of complaint*
>   *‘Good morning,’ we replied in chorus*